# How can I merge changes from a branch that contains a subset of directories from another?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-svn

I'll try to keep this brief.

We have a git repository that is acting as an SVN mirror (managed by BitBucket). This repo contains *every* project in the company since the beginning of time and having every developer clone it is not a reasonable request (25+33GiB full clone and 15+GiB shallow) But even then, we don't need a full clone of the entire repository, just a subset of the directories within.

Using git-subtree, I managed to split out all the directories of interest and figured we could add these directories back in our local repos using git-subtree add. This process is transparent to the svn repository. This works out well and the size is much more manageable (9+6GiB full clone and 8GiB shallow). The problem is I don't know how we could take changes we make in these "partial clones" and merge them back into the master branch.

I thought we'd be able to use the usual pull requests to get them in but since the trees of the branches are different, it doesn't behave like I'd want it to (the missing directories are treated as removals). I just want to merge the changes of the cloned directories and leave the others untouched.

I don't think using a sparse checkout would help here since we still would have to clone the full repo to make it work which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there some combination of commands I can use to make this all work?

---

Here's the (modified) scripts that I used to split out the directories and to checkout the directories of interest:

[split_projects.sh](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/a08fe369fa297f125f834784296763b3)
I used git-subtree to split and rejoin the directories and used git-replace to improve the speed of resplitting (to only process the new commits).  Note that the rejoin is *not* committed to the main repo (I am not willing to try to commit that especially with the svn mirror).

[initial_setup.sh](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/669a26d2eef5bac5be0a765f02064594)
This is the script to prepare the local repo. To be used by Windows users, many of whom are not very experienced with git or command line tools.

[checkout_projects.sh](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/0afd9e9ee1fc6800747a54aa6f99d7ec)
The actual checkout script.

There's another that pulls in updates from the split subdirectories but I'm not including it here.

Comment: What's wrong with the subtree options on merge?

Comment: It's my understanding that using that strategy merges branches where one is fully contained within the other. i.e., branch A is already a subtree of branch B. In my situation, branch A contains a subset of the directories of branch B and wouldn't work.

Comment: You may have to reach out to the mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org) to get support. My gut instinct, though, is that there may not be a solution, since you're seeking to somehow apply changes made in subtrees to the root repo, and I can't imagine how that would be possible without information about the commits in the root repo. If your developers use Windows, the recently open-sourced GVFS project may actually be what you're looking for.

Comment: `Using git-subtree, I managed to split out all the directories ...`
Can you show us the command you used to split the big repo into smaller ones ?

Comment: @JeffMercado, You must have used svn remotes, so the subtree that you created was it on other branch and not master branch ? If not could you give a realtime example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JeffMercado: thanks for posting the scripts. For the `how we could take changes we make in these "partial clones" and merge them back into the master branch.` part : do you want to push the changes from one of the partial clones back to `bigrepo` ?

Comment: @LeGEC: yes, essentially I want to create a workflow for devs who would want to use git in a svn centric environment. If the repo was leaner and didn't have all that fluff, we'd use git-svn. But with the size of the clones, I just don't see that as an option.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want some changes merged back, do your merge `--no-commit` and undo those changes in the merge result before committing.  For unwanted deletions, just `git checkout` the version you want. For unwanted change hunks, `git checkout --patch`.

Another option, which might wind up simpler if it's really just folding in toplevel subtrees missing from the merged branch, is to do the merge and amend it afterwards, a `(git ls-tree @; git ls-tree @^1|grep ^04)|sort -usk4 | git mktree` will generate the right tree easily enough, so

```
fixup=`(git ls-tree @; git ls-tree @^1|grep ^04)|sort -usk4|git mktree`

commit=`git show -s --pretty=%B @|git commit-tree -p @^1 -p @^2 $fixup`

git update-ref -m 'fold in missing subdirectories' @ $commit
```

after the merge and you're done.

Comment: I think I might be able to set up a script to do that. Probably integrated with pull requests to a special branch I will create.

Comment: I will be heading in this direction when I have more time to work on this (it's on the backburner for now).  It'll be the closest I can get with this.

Answer (score 2):

in your case I'm afraid you have to use cherry-picks to move the changes to the original repository

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have is for you to run the following in a sparse checkout of a shallow clone of the root repository:

```
git checkout -b branch-to-PR-in
git fetch remote-with-subtree-as-root
git merge -s recursive -X theirs -X subtree=path/in/root/to/subtree/ remote-with-subtree-as-root/master --allow-unrelated-histories -X theirs
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your scripts correctly :

inside `bigrepo`, a `$project` has its history on *branch* `subdirs/$project`, and its content in the root directory of the repo
e.g : if you run `git checkout subdirs/$project` in `bigrepo`, the content of the project lies in `/` (not in some extra subdirectory).

If this is the case :

I think a sequence of `git subdir push -P $project` should work :

- one from whatever "local repo" to the split repo
- one from the split repo to the `bigrepo`

Comment: While that would push to the split out branches, I ultimately want to get them back to the master branch.  That way changes from the git users get back to the svn repo.

Comment: @JeffMercado: from the docs (`git help subtree`) you should be able to push to any branch you like. Otherwise you can build your tree and commit by hand, as @jthill suggested.